# Slim routes not working on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I'm creating REST API in php slim framework and i was using it just fine. Locally everything is running perfect but I'm having trouble with running it online. I have server from university where there are a lot of student projects so route to my rest api is:

/var/www/projects/myProject/bpsql

In bpsql folder there are public, vendor and app folder with composer.json file. In my public file there is htaccess file which is causing trouble (I think). How should that file look, do you think i should change something from this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I tried with adding line `RewriteBase projects/myproject/bpsql/public`but nothing has worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

```
apache modules on server got by `print_r(apache_get_modules());



     Array
(
    [0] => core
    [1] => mod_log_config
    [2] => mod_logio
    [3] => mod_version
    [4] => prefork
    [5] => http_core
    [6] => mod_so
    [7] => mod_alias
    [8] => mod_auth_basic
    [9] => mod_authn_file
    [10] => mod_authz_default
    [11] => mod_authz_groupfile
    [12] => mod_authz_host
    [13] => mod_authz_user
    [14] => mod_autoindex
    [15] => mod_cgi
    [16] => mod_deflate
    [17] => mod_dir
    [18] => mod_env
    [19] => mod_mime
    [20] => mod_negotiation
    [21] => mod_php5
    [22] => mod_reqtimeout
    [23] => mod_rewrite
    [24] => mod_setenvif
    [25] => mod_ssl
    [26] => mod_status
)
/var/www    //echo getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") ;
```

Comment: What version of Slim are you using?

Comment: My current version is 2.6. Do you think I should update?

Comment: What is the error that you get online?

Comment: There is no error, it just doesnt recognize api or even slim, just:The requested URL /projects/myproject/bpsql/public/questions/7 was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at xxxx.xxx.hr Port 80

Comment: Can you check if the Apache `mod_rewrite` module is enabled?

Comment: You could take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2).

Comment: I enabled rewrite in apacheb but still not working? any suggestions?

Comment: Can you update the result of `apache_get_modules` in the question?

Comment: I edited, extra mode is now enabled with rewrite but i still get error

Comment: Does the base url for your app (`/`) work?

Comment: I'm trying simple hello world, but nothing works, i dont even get slim errors but apache 404 not found? I've tried all rewritebase in htaccess file but none work? RewriteBase /var/www/projects/myprojectsbpsql/public

Comment: Did you try without using the `RewriteBase` directive?

Comment: yes, no luck, could i chat with you for few minuntes via anything if you can try help me enable this. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92053/discussion-between-davide-pastore-and-itodor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, figured the problem so if someone in future encounters same problem, this fixed it for me:

1. Enabling rewrite module in apache (Martin's answer)
2. In httpd conf file i changed `AllowOverRide None` to `AllowOverride All`

Special thanks to @David Pastore for all the help and assistance in figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you are on Linux, but if so. It seems you do not have mod rewrite enabled. So the following could be helpful.

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```